# Remote control Eclipse Debug using JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, remote-debugging, eclipse-jdt

I'm writing an application that needs to remote debug using eclipse JDT. The communication between my app and eclipse is fine and I'm using the following methods to manage breakpoints:

To add a breakpoint:

```
  IJavaLineBreakpoint breakpoint = JDIDebugModel.createLineBreakpoint(...)
```

To remove a breakpoint:

```
  IJavaLineBreakpoint breakpoint = JDIDebugModel.lineBreakpointExists(...);
  breakpoint.delete();
```

To list all breakpoints:

```
 IBreakpointManager mgr = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getBreakpointManager();
 mgr.getBreakpoints();
```

But now my project is "suspended" in the breakpoints I've programatically created and I don't know how to fire actions (STEP_OVER, STEP_INTO,RESUME).I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
DebugPlugin.getDefault().fireDebugEventSet(new DebugEvent[] {new DebugEvent(getResource(projectId, fullClassName), DebugEvent.STEP_OVER)});
```

What I need to know is:

- How can I send step over and step into commands to eclipse debugger;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem doing some research in the eclipse source code.

The trick is that instead of using static methods like I have done on creating breakponts

```
JDIDebugModel.createLineBreakpoint(...)
```

The **resume** and **stepOver** methods are part of the Thread which is beeing executed on debug mode. So I have to save the ILauch object because then it will give me access to debug threads.

```
    // I have to store it in a field for late use.
    ILaunch launch = new Launch(null, ILaunchManager.DEBUG_MODE, null);
    ...
    // Then I can access the thread and call stepover or resume methods
    IDebugTarget target = launch.getDebugTarget(); 
    IThread[] threads = target.getThreads();
    threads[0].stepOver();
    threads[0].resume();
    threads[0].stepInto();
```